# Using a CSS id with f.select in html.slim

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm baffled trying to figure out how to put a css id into an f.select, using html.slim template (I loathe .slim, but unfortunately, working on someone else's project).  Here is what I have:

```
= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, @user.state), id: "state-dropdown")
```

I have tried moving parenthesis around and every other combination I can think of, but it simply doesn't work. The code above will load, but it doesn't actually do anything, and to further confuse me, when I inspect the element, it shows it as having an id of "user_state".

I know I'm probably missing something obvious, but the html.slim documentation is really lacking. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

In case it matters, it is `Rails 4.0.0 ruby 2.1.2p95`.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select), `html_options = {}` is the last argument, so that it should be:

```
= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, @user.state), {}, id: "state-dropdown")
```